# Error al crear objeto Circle en ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic, google-maps, variables, ionic3

Hola estoy utilizando el api de Google maps. Donde tengo que crear un circulo alrededor del market creado.  Lo realizo con (funciona correcto)

```
createCircle(loc: LatLng){

    return  this.map.addCircle(
      {'center': loc,
      'radius': 300,
      'strokeColor' : '#AA00FF',
      'strokeWidth': 5,
      'fillColor' : '#880000'}

    );;

}
```

Mi error aparece cuando intento crear una variable Circle

```
circle:Circle;
```

y trato de cambiar el método por

```
  createCircle(loc: LatLng){

 this.circle =   this.map.addCircle(
      {'center': loc,
      'radius': 300,
      'strokeColor' : '#AA00FF',
      'strokeWidth': 5,
      'fillColor' : '#880000'}

    );

    return this.circle;
}
```

Me aparece este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es mi error .. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me respondo realice lo siguiente

```
circle:Circle;
```

y cambie el método por

```
createCircle(loc: LatLng){

    this.map.addCircle({
      'center': loc,
      'radius': this.radius,
      'strokeColor': '#AA00FF',
      'strokeWidth': 5,
      'fillColor': '#880000'
    }).then((circle: Circle) => {
      this.circle = circle;
    })

    return this.circle;
}
```